# My string is too long for my node. I need more space

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees, forest

((I was supported from **@Skillmon**. He is the owner of this code.))
I have a forest tree with a page break.
My string is too long for my node. The horizontal line must be longer. In the past i used  `before computing xy={l=100pt},` but now it does not work.

See my post before -> [My if condition does not work. Any idea why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452922/my-if-condition-does-not-work-any-idea-why/452926#452926)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot,abstract=on,multi,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{storebox}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%Zeilenumbruch in der tikz Umgebung!
% addaswyd o gôd Sašo Živanović: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296771/
\def\hiddenparcommand{\par}
\newcommand\otherhiddenparcommand{\par\noindent}
\newcommand\hiddencommacommand{, }
\forestset{%
    declare keylist register={split here ids},% the list of nodes to split the tree at
    split here ids={},
    declare keylist register={split here interjects},% the list of comments to put in between the tree parts
    split here interjects={},
    declare keylist={split here auto siblings}{},% a list to hold the siblings which need edge restoration
    declare toks register=split here toks,
    declare dimen register=tmpdima,
    tmpdima'=0pt,
    declare dimen register=tmpdimb,
    tmpdimb'=0pt,
    declare dimen register=tmpdimc,
    tmpdimc'=0pt,
    to widest/.style={
        tikz+={\path (\forestregister{tempdima}, \forestoption{y}) -- (\forestregister{tempdimb}, \forestoption{y});},
    },
    hide commas/.style={%
        split here toks+={\hiddencommacommand},
        split here toks+={#1},
    },
    split dir tree pre/.style={%
        label={[text=gray, anchor=north, font=\scriptsize]below:{[cont.]}{}},
    },
    split dir tree post/.style={%
        label={[font=\scriptsize, anchor=south, text=gray]above:{[cont.]}{}},
    },
    split dir tree auto post/.style={% this gets applied to the first node after a break
        split dir tree post,
        tempkeylistc'={},
        tmpdimb/.option=y,
        for nodewalk={
            while={
                > ORw2+d _+d < On=! & {y}{tmpdimb}{##2-##1} {\textheight-#1} {n'}{1}%
            }{
                next,
                tempkeylistc/.option=name
            }%
        }{},
        % save the list
        split here auto siblings/.register=tempkeylistc,
        tikz+/.process={% this tries to redraw the edges to the following siblings
            OOw2{edge}{id}%
            {%
                \path [##1] (!u.parent anchor |- .north) ++(\forestregister{folder indent},1ex) coordinate (before ##2) |- (.child anchor);
                \edef\tempa{\foresteoption{split here auto siblings}}
                \foreach \i in \tempa \path [##1] (before ##2) |- ({forest cs:\i.child anchor});
            }%
        },
    },
    split dir tree/.code={%
        \forestset{%
            draw tree stage/.style={
                for root'={
                    tempdima/.min={%
                        >OOw2+d{x}{min x}{####1+####2}%
                    }{tree},
                    tempdimb/.max={%
                        >OOw2+d{x}{max x}{####1+####2}%
                    }{tree},
                    for tree={%
                        to widest,
                    },
                },
                tempcountb'=-1,
                do until={%
                    strequal((split_here_ids),"")
                }{%
                    tempkeylistb'={},
                    tempkeylista'={},
                    split register={split here ids}{,}{tempcounta,tempkeylistb+},
                    split register={split here interjects}{,}{temptoksa,tempkeylista+},
                    split here ids'/.register=tempkeylistb,
                    split here interjects'/.register=tempkeylista,
                    % Sašo Živanović: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28484520#28484520
                    for nodewalk={%
                        draw tree processing order/.style={%
                            filter={tree}{> ORw+n< OR> & {id}{tempcounta}{########1+1}{id}{tempcountb}}%
                        }%
                    }{},
                    for root'={draw tree},
                    TeX/.process={Rw{temptoksa}{\otherhiddenparcommand ####1\hiddenparcommand}},
                    tempcountb'/.register=tempcounta,
                },
                for nodewalk={%
                    draw tree processing order/.style={%
                        filter={tree}{>OR>{id}{tempcountb}}%
                    }%
                }{},
                for root'={draw tree},
            },
        }%
    },
    split dir here auto/.style n args=2{%
        split dir tree pre,
        !next node.split dir tree auto post=#2,
        split here ids+/.option=id,
        %     !next node.split resume here ids+/.option=id,
        split={#1}{,}{split here toks,hide commas},
        split here interjects/.register=split here toks,
    },
    split dir tree auto/.style={%
        split dir tree,
        before drawing tree={%
            tempdima/.max={y}{tree},
            tempdimc/.register=tempdima,
            tempdimd/.min={y}{tree},
            tempdima-/.register=tempdimd,
            tempdimb'=\textheight,
            tmpdima'=10ex,
            tmpdimc'=\pagetotal,
            while={%
                >RR>{tempdima}{tempdimb}%
            }{%
                for nodewalk={%
                    root',
                    until={%
                        > ROw2+d RRw2+d > {tempdimc}{y}{##1-##2} {tmpdima}{tmpdimc}{\textheight-##2-##1}%
                    }{next node},
                    previous node,
                    split dir here auto/.process={R_w2{tmpdima}{continued}{{##2}{##1}}},
                    next node,
                    tempdima/.option=y,
                    tempdimc/.register=tempdima,
                    tempdima-/.register=tempdimd,
                    tmpdima'=15ex,
                    tmpdimc'=0pt
                }{},
            },
        },
    },
}
%Zeilenumbruch in der tikz Umgebung! Ende

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_helmutW_box
\cs_new_protected:Npx \helmutW_replace_verb_newline:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn #1 { \char_generate:nn { 13 } { 12 } } { #2 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npx \helmutW_replace_verb_newline_newline:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn #1
      { \char_generate:nn { 13 } { 12 } \char_generate:nn { 13 } { 12 } } { #2 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \helmutW_process_verb_newline:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \ProcessedArgument { #3 }
    \helmutW_replace_verb_newline_newline:Nn \ProcessedArgument { #2 }
    \helmutW_replace_verb_newline:Nn \ProcessedArgument { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \AutoSplittedTree
  {
    s
    O{ for~tree = { folder, grow'=0, fit=band, } }
    >{ \helmutW_process_verb_newline:nnn { ~ } { ~ \par } } +v
  }
  {
    \par
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
      { \iftrue }
      {
        \vbox_set:Nn \l_helmutW_box { \helmutW_tree:n { #2, #3 } }
        \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_ht:N \l_helmutW_box } >
          { \dim_min:nn { \pagegoal-\pagetotal } { \textheight } }
          {
            \iftrue
          }
          {
            \box_use:N \l_helmutW_box
            \iffalse
          }
      }
      \helmutW_tree:n { #2, split~dir~tree~auto, #3 }
    \fi
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \helmutW_tree:n #1
  {
    \scantokens
      {
        \begin{forest}
          #1
        \end{forest}%
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}    
\AutoSplittedTree
  {
    [ XYZ
      [ XYZ
        [ XYZ,edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}
         [ XYZ,edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{3}} ]
         [ XYZ,edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{AA}} ]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
             [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}]
         [ XYZ,edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{4}} ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: To be fair one should mention that I only coded the `\AutoSplittedTree` macro, the Ti*k*Z related code is from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296771/

Comment: I need help :) Can somebody help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your problem, if I add `before computing xy={l=100pt}`

```
\AutoSplittedTree
  {
    [ XYZ
      [ XYZ
        [ XYZ,before computing xy={l=100pt},edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{Too longggggggg}}
         [ XYZ,edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{3}} ]
         [ XYZ,edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{AA}} ]
         [ XYZ,edge label={node[pos=0.75,above,font=\scriptsize]{4}} ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I get

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what to write where. Isn't the `\AutoSplittedTree` exactly from the (M) not working example?

Comment: @KeksDose, no I added the `before computing xy={l=100pt}`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer i used your solution but it does not work if i a have a pagebreak. Only at the first page it works. At the second page my string gets lost. See my Update Code. Mein "Node String" verschwindet beim Pagebreak. Wissen Sie warum das nicht funktioniert?

Comment: That's a quite different question and obviously not related to the length of the string. Ask a new question - a try to make a shorter example. You can e.g. change the textheight to avoid so many leafs.