# \dim_set failed when using \str_if_in in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, latex3

Here is the MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \l__xchoices_coffin_join_horizontal_sep_dim
\str_new:N \l__xchoices_coffin_current_label_pos_str
\str_set:Nn \l__xchoices_coffin_current_label_pos_str {left}
\cs_new:Npn \__xchoices_label_hsep_init:N #1
  {
    \dim_set:Nn \l__xchoices_coffin_join_horizontal_sep_dim
      {
        \str_if_in:NnTF #1 {left}
          { 5pt }
          {
            \str_if_in:NnTF #1 {right}
              {-5pt}
              {0pt}
          }
      }
  }
\__xchoices_label_hsep_init:N
  \l__xchoices_coffin_current_label_pos_str
% \dim_use:N \l__xchoices_coffin_join_horizontal_sep_dim
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

but it failed to compile, and the fatal message is:

```bash
Missing number, treated as zero
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
```

I don't know what's going on with it.

Comment: No `\…_if_in:…` conditional is expandable

Comment: Why does it involves in expandability? (I'm a LaTeX3 new learner, not so familiar with it)

Comment: Doesn't the TF of str_if_in come in the input stream or output stream?

Comment: @xdyy Search for  "Fully expandable functions" in interface3 then read  that, you'll understand. (if you don't, recursively read up on the terms)

Comment: See also (maybe) [macros - What is "expansion"? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158827/what-is-expansion)  [page breaking - My if condition does not work. Any idea why? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452922/my-if-condition-does-not-work-any-idea-why)

Comment: [search tag] Why can't I use unexpandable function that evaluates to a value/dimension/string etc. inside an argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### A very short course on macro expansion

TeX tokens can be *expandable* or *unexpandable*. Macros (those defined with `\def` or variants thereof, such as `\cs_new:Npn`) are of the first kind and also some primitives.

When TeX processes its input it first builds tokens and then proceeds to expand tokens, if possible. If not, it sends tokens, absorbed according to the syntax rules of the found unexpandable token, to the next stage (which is outside of user's control).

The `\dim_set:Nn` instruction is, for instance, unexpandable. In legacy TeX terms you have something similar to

```
\newdimen\foo
\foo=\dimexpr ... \relax
```

The token `\foo` is not expandable, so it's sent to the next stage where it's recognized as a `<dimen>` register, so TeX requests more input according to the syntax rules, which allow for `=` and then want something that can be interpreted as a (fixed) length. OK, `\dimexpr` is good, but it's by itself unexpandable. Same story, it's sent up and down it comes a request for more input.

In this case, macro expansion is performed, so if you had `\def\baz{640pt}` and TeX finds `\baz` while providing new tokens for `\dimexpr`, it will be happy. But if it finds something that doesn't fit the syntax rules for `\dimexpr`, then it will stop looking for more tokens and the next stage has to use what it had.

#### What's going wrong in your case?

The second argument to `\dim_set:Nn` must only contain tokens that, at the end of the expansion process only leave unexpandable tokens that fit the syntax of `\dimexpr`.

Unfortunately, `\str_if_in:NNTF` doesn't. You can deduce it from the fact that in the `interface3` manual it is not followed by a star. So the fact that its processing can (and actually does) not *at once* provide for one of the last two arguments is documented.

[image]

#### What can you do?

In the picture I added also `\str_case:nn(TF)` to show that the instructions in this set *are* expandable.

If your string variable is only expected to contain `left` or `right` (so no need to test with `\str_if_in:nnTF`), you can use `\str_case:VnF`:

```
\dim_set:Nn \l__xchoices_coffin_join_horizontal_sep_dim
 {
  \str_case:VnF #1
   {
    {left}{5pt}
    {right}{-5pt}
   }
   {0pt}
 }
```

Otherwise you need to have the `\dim_set:Nn` instruction inside the cases

```
    \str_if_in:NnTF #1 {left}
      {
        \dim_set:Nn \l__xchoices_coffin_join_horizontal_sep_dim {5pt}
      }
      {
        \str_if_in:NnTF #1 {right}
          {
            \dim_set:Nn \l__xchoices_coffin_join_horizontal_sep_dim {-5pt}
          }
          {
            \dim_set:Nn \l__xchoices_coffin_join_horizontal_sep_dim {0pt}
          }
      }
```

In either case, `\cs_new:Npn \__xchoices_label_hsep_init:N #1` should be

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xchoices_label_hsep_init:N #1
```

because this function performs *unexpandable* actions.

Comment: Thanks sooo much for your detailed explanation!